# Route token that includes forward slashes

Tags: routes, routing

I'm setting up a route in control panel. I'd like to use a token that is similar to asterisk but involves forward slashes. Here's an example:

I want to route everything from site.com/blog/* to a single template.
If I route **site.com/blog/some-uri-identifier** , it works fine and I'm able to get **"some-uri-identifier"** in my template (using slug option).
I need to route **site.com/blog/some/uri/identifier-long-name** and still go to the same template + get **"/some/uri/identifier-long-name"** in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CP route settings don’t have a token for matching multiple URI segments. However you can pull it off from **craft/config/routes.php** instead:

```php
return array(
    'blog/(.+)' => 'path/to/template',
);
```

You’ll be able to access whatever was captured by `(.*)` from your templates via `matches[1]`.